# Pug-Template not importing CSS

Tags: html, css, pug

im trying to create a Website with node.js and express with Pug as template  language. 
Im using  Bootstrap css also.

My problem is  that pug doesnt  seem  to import  my own css, but imports the Bootstrap css and I do not understand why.

I tried  using different  folders /  no folders and placing the css in the same folder as the pug file but that didnt work either.

I also was trying to replace the content of  the css with something basic like giving the  whole body or header block an background-color but that didnt work  either.

Any help would be awesome  because I couldnt find someone  else  with this problem.

Here  is my  pug file:

```
head
  title= title

  //Bootstrap
  link(rel="stylesheet", href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css", integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u", crossorigin="anonymous")
  link(rel="stylesheet", href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css", integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp", crossorigin="anonymous")

  //Jquery
  script(src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js", integrity="sha256-iT6Q9iMJYuQiMWNd9lDyBUStIq/8PuOW33aOqmvFpqI=", crossorigin="anonymous")

  //Own
  link(rel="stylesheet", type="text/css", href="../css/navbar.css")
  script(src="../javascript/navbar.js")

  p  test

  nav
    div(class="menu-icon")
      i(class="fa fa-bars fa-2x")

    div(class="logo")
      LOGO
    div(class="menu")
      ul
        li
          a(href="/") Home
        li
          a(href="/") Home2
```

And my css file:

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue",sans-serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url(https://wallpaper.wiki/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/wallpaper.wiki-Beautiful-Full-HD-Wallpaper-Download-Free-PIC-WPE0010098.jpg) no-repeat 50% 50%;
  background-size: cover;
}

.content {
  width: 94%;
  margin: 4em auto;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: justify;
}

.logo {
  line-height: 60px;
  position: fixed;
  float: left;
  margin: 16px 46px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 60px;
}

nav ul {
  line-height: 60px;
  list-style: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: right;
  margin: 0;
  padding-right: 40px;
  transition: 1s;
}

nav.black ul {
  background: #000;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 16px 40px;;
}

nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.menu-icon {
  line-height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
  text-align: right;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 15px 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  display: none;
}

@media(max-width: 786px) {

  .logo {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        margin-top: 16px;
  }

  nav ul {
        max-height: 0px;
        background: #000;
  }

  nav.black ul {
        background: #000;
  }

  .showing {
        max-height: 34em;
  }

  nav ul li {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 24px;
        text-align: center;
  }

  .menu-icon {
        display: block;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution,

I needed to add the line:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/static'));
```

to my node server and then put the css into an folder inside of the static folder.